# How to use Snap.svg code multiple times?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeKJJv) .

I want to make Icons using Snap.svg, so i want end user to repeating HTML to getting multiple icons.

HTML:

```
<svg class="box"></svg>
<svg class="box"></svg>    <!-- not work -->
<svg class="box"></svg>    <!-- not work -->
<svg class="box"></svg>    <!-- not work -->
```

JS:

```
var box = Snap(".box");
box.rect(0,0,100,100).attr({fill:f00});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through each `.box` and instantiate Snap on each element, this is an example:

```
var boxes = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));
boxes.forEach(function(box){
  var box = Snap(box);
  box.rect(0,0,100,100).attr({fill:"#f00"});
});
```

Working example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKXpEY