# SVG Sizing that's Cross-Browser Compatible

Tags: html, css, image, svg, cross-browser

I'm new to using SVG sprites but after watching a tree house video on SVG sprites I'm giving it a go. I'm using the same formatting they did in the video for a link with a background image of an SVG pulled from the sprite, namely:

```
<a href="whatever" class="helpmepls"></a>
```

Where the styles are:

```
.helpmepls {
    background: url("sprite.svg") no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: -32px -128px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(2.0);
    -o-transform: scale(2.0);
    transform: scale(2.0);
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However whenever scaling the images larger than 1.0 they become pixelated in Edge (and probably IE, haven't checked) even though they look good in Chrome. Help on how to make browser-compatible? Do I need to be using a container, an svg element, a view element, viewbox, or some combination of those?

Comment: @sohaib - Thanks for editing the syntax of the question to capitalize the letters SVG. Regarding the actual content of the question, do you have a suggested solution?

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601958/svg-sizing-thats-cross-browser-compatible/39619698#39619698) Please tell me if everything going well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkLVpr/left/) ! You can download it from [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/share/zip/kkLVpr/).

> [My workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06atTvwkuJE)

You could control the scaling by changing the value of `scaleValue` from line 1 in JS.

```
var scaleValue = 1.2;
```

I usually use "inline" SVG and the GreenSock library to make animations!

Comment: I used `transform: scale(1.3);` for scaling!

Comment: Yeah transform: scale(1.3); what I'm currently using and it appears blurry in Edge. I'm using it as a background image in an <a> tag. I think this article has the answer I'm looking for in it but I'm not understanding how to implement it: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

However, your fiddle looks great in Edge for me! So I'll study that. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome dude! I just read the article and made a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/dpk7b871/2/ You could control to scaling by modifying `width: 20%` in `scaling` class! this is option #2 in the article.

Comment: I usually use option #3 in the article (Inline SVG) when I made very complex animation: http://codepen.io/smalinux/pen/yJwJjm/left/

Comment: You've done so much work on this answer that I feel compelled to accept it as the 'right' answer (which I've done). But I am still stuck on trying to use a single sprite.svg sheet that contains MULTIPLE icons each of size 32px by 32px, grabbing just the one I need (using background-position: x,y,), and scaling it to 64px by 64px and looking good in Edge.

Comment: Hmm! I think you will need some JS codes! look at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37731704/5688267 . I made collection of icons using this technic: https://codecanyon.net/item/social-neon-icons-animated-svg-icons/16638551?s_rank=1